# PySimpleGUI update method, Does not update the whole InputText Box

Tags: python, pysimplegui

[image: gui]I have a function in my pysimblegui project that receives many strings and displays only the first 6 characters in a multiline box, It saves the original input in Json memory and updates the Input text box.

but so far, the update method only updates the first 32 characters leaving the remaining characters in the Input text box.

What is the cause of the bug and how can I fix it? I want to clear the whole input text box after every event, not just the first 32 characters.

```py
 layout = [
        [sg.Text('\n             Group Added \n', font=(NORMAL_STRING_FONT, 15), text_color='black', justification='center')],
        
        [sg.Text('List of scanned devices:', font=(TITLE_FONTS, 12), text_color='black', justification='left')],
         #multiline input
        [ sg.Multiline(key=AllEvt.gpMultilineKey.value, enable_events=True, autoscroll=True, size=(60,4),
                    background_color='#999999', font=NORMAL_STRING_FONT, disabled=True )],
    enter code here

    #inputtext box
        [sg.InputText(key=AllEvt.gpInputTextKey.value, enable_events=True, size=(60, 1))],
        [sg.Button('\n Add \n', key=AllEvt.gpAddGroup.value, button_color=('#000000', '#b6eada'), size=(8, 1))]
    ]
    return layout

def updateMultilineBx(globalVar: AppGlobal, values):
    
    input_text = values[AllEvt.gpInputTextKey.value]
    # Define a regular expression pattern to match the expected format of a scanned line
    pattern = r"^[a-f0-9]{32}"
    # Check if the input text matches the expected format of a scanned line
    if re.match(pattern, input_text):
        # Append the full line to the JSON memory
        globalVar.gp_json_memory.append(input_text)


        globalVar.win[AllEvt.gpMultilineKey.value].update(input_text[:6] + "\n", append=True)
        if globalVar.win[AllEvt.gpInputTextKey.value].get():
            # Clear the InputText element
            globalVar.win[AllEvt.gpInputTextKey.value].update('')
         
                
    dbg('line appended')
    dbg('update multiline with input')
```

![gui 2023-09-08 151708]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the exact question is, but demo code for you.

```py
import re
import PySimpleGUI as sg


pattern = r"^[a-f0-9]{32}"

layout = [
    [sg.Multiline(autoscroll=True, size=(60,4), disabled=True, key="Multiline")],
    [sg.InputText(focus=True, do_not_clear=False, expand_x=True, key="Input"),
     sg.Button("Add")],
]
window = sg.Window('Demo', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == 'Add':
        input_text = values['Input']
        if re.match(pattern, input_text):
            window["Multiline"].update(input_text[:6] + "\n", append=True)

window.close()
```

Comment: The project I am working on is very big,  It has many events. I added all events in An AllEvt Enum class. 

The only way I can write events  is through functions. @Jason Yang

Comment: Through function or not, there should be nothing different.

Comment: I mean I want to clear my InputText box after the value is appended to the Multiline Box. But for some reason, only the first 32 characters are cleared using the `.update('')` method

Comment: There should be something wrong not provided in your code for only the first-32 characters cleared, IMO, the problem is not in the method `update`. If possible, show us an executable code, so we can find the issue by our side. Add option `do_not_clear=False` as above code to clear the content of Input element after each event.

Comment: I tried `do_not_clear=False` but it happens to clear all the inputs before the event. I will provide more code about the function.  @Jason Yang

Comment: I want to clarify and explain the logic I want to carry out with my function.  If you check the  `Layout` code I have a **Multiline** box with key `Multiline(key=AllEvt.gpMultilineKey.value` and an **InputText** box with Key `key=AllEvt.gpInputTextKey.value`. They is also an Add button but, I am not using it in that function. My goal with the Add button is to add all the appended texts in the multiline box and handle it in another function in the backend.  However,  my goal for this function is to read texts/characters from a barcodescanner. Append the first 6 characters and clear InputText.

Comment: The output from the barcode scanner looks like this when i print it on a notepad:
`42e9418c13544b09ac22fadad6dd8c2a

SRD3-D10-123-234-445-677-WL-BL`
The first line is a UUID and the second is the product name.   It automatically prints 2 lines. I don't know if it is a `\n` or `\r` that separates the two lines.  When I run the code,  It appends the first 6 characters to the multiline box, but only clears the first 32 characters. `(update("")`.  I goal is anytime I can the Input, It should append the first ^ characters and clear every text.

Comment: If nothing wrong,What you talked about all mean no problem to you. Again, if possible, show us an executable code which can duplicate your question, so we can find the issue by our side.

Comment: sorry I made some typos in my last comment.    The problem I am having is,  The `update("")` method is failing to clear every texts from the InputText Box after the Event.  I want to clear every text in The InputText box and not only the first line after the Event. How can i do this @Jason Yang.  I will add a picture of the GUI above

Comment: It mean nohing to me and cannot help people to help you.